# how to use free telerik dll for mvc3 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I wanted to use `simple telerik grid control`.i don't go for telerik rad control or anything else.i didn't get free telerik "dll" reference for MVC3 Razor.please let me know where we could get free telerik "dll".

Answer (score 0):

You can get it on codeplex : http://telerikaspnetmvc.codeplex.com/ or on NuGet http://www.nuget.org/packages/TelerikMvcExtensions/